# Search icon not showing in HTML & CSS (Adobe Dreamweaver CC 2019)

Tags: html, css, icons, font-awesome

I've been working on a little assignment and can't seem to get the search icon to appear in the search bar. I've looked everywhere for answers and its really bugging me haha. I would say I'm a beginner in HTML and css so if there are any stupid mistakes, please do understand.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        .searchbar {display: inline-block;
            float: right;
            padding: 20px 0px}
.searchbar input[type=text] {border:none;
                         font-family: courier;
                         font-size: 18px;
                         font-style: italic;
                         }

.searchbar button {float: right;
               padding:12px;
               background: #ddd;
               font-size: 12px;
               border: none;
               cursor: pointer;
              }
</style>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="searchbar">
        <input type="text" placeholder="search...">
        <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to include FontAwesome.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to use a [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/) icon. Font Awesome is an icon font library delivered via CSS. Therefore, you need to include the Font Awesome CSS on your page for the `.fa` and `.fa-search` CSS classes to work.

```css
.searchbar {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  padding: 20px 0px
}

.searchbar input[type=text] {
  border: none;
  font-family: courier;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: italic;
}

.searchbar button {
  float: right;
  padding: 12px;
  background: #ddd;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="searchbar">
  <input type="text" placeholder="search...">
  <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah crap, I just edited his snippet to include it. Hey @user10803421 if this answers your question I edited your question incorrectly and should revert it. PS, welcome to SO :)

Comment: 10-4, thanks. I assumed he was asking about his floats etc, should have paid more attention on my part. Cheers